# Regression of IntelliJ IDEA 14 support for Spock Framework?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, spock

After upgrading from IDEA 13.1.x to 14.x (14.0.2 at the moment) I see the support for Spock Framework Mock() and Stub() methods got worse.

To be more specific, I mean in-line methods stubbing/mocking with closures like:

```
MyType stub = Stub {
    myMethod() >> { /* do something */ }
}
```

IDEA 13 *is aware* of available methods for stubbed type, which is visible on the below screen shot.

[image: IDEA 13 Spock Stub support]

`size()` method is not underlined. It can be navigated to, auto-completed, checked for possible argument types and so on - usual IDE stuff. The same is possible with any other `List` method inside of the 'stub closure'.

While IDEA 14 lacks this feature which really is a pity. The screen shot below shows it.

[image: IDEA 14 Spock Stub support]

`size()` method is underlined and greyed out. IDE seems to not have a clue what's up.

The same applies to `Mock { }` method event if invoked with a type as an argument like  `Mock(MyType) { }` (and `Stub(MyType) { }` respectively)

My question is - is it only me or that's a bug/regression? Or maybe I need to adjust some settings?

EDIT: seems it's a bug / regression. I raised a [bug in youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135033). Up vote, please.

Comment: same here.  also half of the time it even forgets what `with` means.

Comment: Maybe the intellij bug tracker is a better place than stackoverflow? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @tim_yates of course it is. I only wanted to confirm it's not only my env issue before raising a ticket. Now as I have this knowledge I'm going to do it and post url to the ticket back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in storage system, i.e. GDSL works itself, but state is inconsistent across IDE startups.

As a temporary solution:

- Project View -> External Libraries -> spock-core
- open `org.spockframework.idea.spock.gdsl` in Editor
- wait until Notification about disabled GDSL comes out
- use Activate link in the Notification

You should enable GDSL every time you start up your Idea.

This bug is fixed and the fix will be released asap.